# Gradle can't find plugin only on windows

Tags: c++, gradle

I'm trying to use Gradle to build the google-test example included in the samples folder with the download. On OS X and Linux it compiles correctly, but on Windows I get the error `Plugin with id "google-test" not found.`

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "cpp"
apply plugin: "google-test"

model {
    flavors {
        passing
        failing
    }
    platforms {
        x86 {
            architecture "x86"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            googleTest {
                headers.srcDir "libs/googleTest/1.7.0/include"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile =
                        file("libs/googleTest/1.7.0/lib/" +
                             findGoogleTestCoreLibForPlatform(targetPlatform))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    components {
        operators(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            targetPlatform "x86"
        }
    }
}

binaries.withType(GoogleTestTestSuiteBinarySpec) {
    lib library: "googleTest", linkage: "static"

    if (flavor == flavors.failing) {
        cppCompiler.define "PLUS_BROKEN"
    }
}

tasks.withType(RunTestExecutable) {
    args "--gtest_output=xml:test_detail.xml"
}

def findGoogleTestCoreLibForPlatform(Platform platform) {
    if (platform.operatingSystem.windows) {
        return "vs2013/gtest.lib"
//        return "vs2013/gtest-core.lib"
//        return "cygwin/gtest-core.lib"
//        return "mingw/gtest-core.lib"
    } else if (platform.operatingSystem.macOsX) {
        return "osx/libgtest.a"
    } else {
        return "linux/libgtest.a"
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the gradle version that you installed on windows/macosx. I'm not sure but I think the google-test plugin comes with version 2.5 rc
https://docs.gradle.org/release-candidate/release-notes#google-test-support

Comment: Thank you, I used jenkins to automatically install it, and it turns out it installed different versions on the two systems.